# Highcharts.js, disable chart animation on render

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts, disable

Does anyone know how to disable animation on render in highchart.js?

In the example here, we set the animations prop to false. It stops animation when you click 'update chart'.

```
    chart: {
    animation: false
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/06h5kor1/

But if you hit refresh, it will still use animations. This would also happen during page navigations, is there a way to simply disable animation like it does with the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling animation on a chart level affects only chart updating. The initial series animation needs to be disabled on a series level.

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      animation: false
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xzyo96fd/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.animation